# $.post is not working in combination with $J = jQuery.noConflict();

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, post

I am having a problem with posting data from javascript to php.I am using the $.post method, though due to conflicts with wordpress I am alos using $J = jQuery.noConflict().

Therefore consequently I have the following, in javascript:

```
$J = jQuery.noConflict()
x=1
$J.post('/the directory',{x: x}, function(data){
});
alert($J.cookie("y"));
```

In php I have:

```
if(isset($_POST['x']))
{
setcookie("y", 1);
}
else{
setcookie("y", -1);
}
```

Every time I get to see that y = -1, indicating that x in php is not found. What am i doing wrong?

What did I try so far, which all did not work:

Connecting the post to different events (when submit is pressed, or when page is loaded)

Putting the alert ($J.cookie("y")) between the brackets which are behind the function (data)

Trying to remove the J after the $ or adding them up front in php

I am a bit afraid that the problem of the post is because I added $J = jQuery.noConflict(). Though I used many other functionality and then I did not have any problem, do you maybe know the solution or can you help me into the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just an FYI, but have you read the [***Codex part***](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) about how to use jQuery in Wordpress ?

Comment: Why do you suspect the issue is with the `noConflict()` and alias? Does the request succeed when using `jQuery.post()` with the same arguments?

Comment: Hi Jonathan, the reason I suspect this, is that this is for me an unknown territory. Next to that have I checked multiple possibilities. The post is not working and the only reason I can imagine is a conflict with the noconflict attribute, but I ask the queston, because I do not know. Next to that have I addred to much scripting to get ride of all the noconflict argumentents/ adjustments..

Answer (score 0):

The entire premise is faulty, cookies are part of the HTTP header being sent with every request, and to receive new cookies you would have to receive a new header, which would require a pageload.

You can't do an ajax request and set a cookie on the server, and then expect it to be accessible in javascript on the clientside without actually reloading the page and receiving the new and modified headers containing that cookie.

Comment: Ok I get the point, but I am not sure how I can then solve my problem. I have a form which is submitted at the end. Then the page loads and I redirect the visitor back to the same page. During this moment (this page load) I want php to get the data, process the data and bring back the information to javascript which i want to show. Now I connect the post to this submit moment, but it is not working, how would you solve this?

Comment: You can send data back and forth with ajax, that's what it's there for. Cookies are for storing persistent data across pageloads and sessions.

Comment: Ok but right here it goes wrong at the post moment, as the x is not recognised, while the cookies do work (I get the -1). How would you solve this post problem?

Comment: I have no idea why `$_POST['x']` wouldn't be set, the posted code looks fine, assuming the URL is correct and the data is really sent.

Comment: Yeah, if I drill it down, the post seems to be the problem, which I haven't solved.. Anyways thank for your your help!